# Calling controller from other places

Tags: symfony

Suppose that we have a controller which is used as a web service. Can we call it inside model classes or views or etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? You may render controller partials in views for example, but you need to be more explicit ^^

Comment: My web service gets an id as input and retrieve sth from database and output an object or xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do whatever you want actually, but MVC flow would be butchered this way.

I assume your webservice has routes like `/api/users/98385`, and returns the user representation if you perform a GET request over such URL.

You can't refer to controllers *inside* the model, that would tightly couple the two: if you need to inject content inside a model, you do this inside a controller - anyway you always delegate your **ORM** to hydrate models.

Views are responsable for **rendering** stuff, so you'd just fetch your data inside your controller, then pass it to the view.

You may make an async call to your webservice **after** the page has been loaded, but this goes beyond server code's scope.

As I always advise, have a look at [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html), it's the fastest way to get a clue on a smooth symfony app development.